# Update FieldX in table for records with common FieldY

Tags: mysql

I have a table where different named records can share a FieldA with a common value. So records 1,3,5 can have FieldA=X and records 2,5,11 can have FieldA=Y.

FieldB can either be NULL or 1.

FieldC is the Name Field.

I am trying to write an update query that will find for each group of records with the same FieldA which record has FieldB=1 and then write the Name field of that record to each of the group's Field D.

I hope I have explained that well, I don't know if there is a table version of SqlFiddle

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked:

```
Update TableA as T1
Inner Join TableA as T2
On T1.FieldX=T2.FieldX
Set T1.FieldD=T2.FieldC
Where T2.FieldB is not NULL
```